# Border for elements which are inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to apply a border for the div element. Since the div element is inline the border is overlapping.

[Example fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/7g8zh90o/1/)

Expected output:

```
<span class="label_no" title="Label Editing not allowed">1.</span>
<div class="Heading">Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....</div>
```

Need label & heading should be in the same line, and border for heading alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
      .Heading{
    font-family: Georgia,"New Century Schoolbook",serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    line-height: 1em;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.label_no{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:red;
}
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/7g8zh90o/5/)

Or

One more Example:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/7g8zh90o/13/)

Comment: Thanks , but i have another case . when there is multiple div elements this will not work. fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7g8zh90o/7/

Comment: ya ok wait sir @MohanaPriyaG_SPS

Answer (score 1):

use this method add `float:left` for the `label` and `display:table` for the text
 - by setting `display:table` it takes the space available

```css
.Heading {
  font-family: Georgia, "New Century Schoolbook", serif;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.label_no {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<span class="label_no" title="Label Editing not allowed">1.</span>

<div class="Heading">Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....</div>
<span class="label_no" title="Label Editing not allowed">1.</span>

<div class="Heading">Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....</div>
<span class="label_no" title="Label Editing not allowed">1.</span>

<div class="Heading">Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use floating on span element like,

```
.label_no{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:red;
    float:left;    
}
```

```css
.Heading{
    font-family: Georgia,"New Century Schoolbook",serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    line-height: 1em;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.label_no{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:red;
    float:left;    
}
```

```html
<span class="label_no" title="Label Editing not allowed">1.</span>
<div class="Heading">Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....Heading Text Goes Here.....</div>
```